# Open Cart Filters

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

what is the correct technique to use filters in opencart? I have been trying long enough to try and add filters to some products on my online shop, but it never seems to work correctly. Can someone explain the technique behind the functioning of filters in opencart.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Catalog > Filters and select Insert to create a filter group. Assign a filter group name (e.g. Color) and add filter name values (e.g. Blue, Red, Yellow).
2. Go to Catalog > Categories and Edit a category. Under the Data tab add the filters you want to be able to apply to that category (e.g. Color > Blue, Color > Red).
3. Go to Catalog > Products and Edit a product. Under the Links tab add the filters which apply to the product (e.g. Color > Blue). Apply to as many products as applicable.
4. Go to Extensions > Modules > Filter. If not installed select Install. Click Edit. Click the Add Module button and under Layout select Category and set Status to Enabled. Set whatever position and sort order you would like.

& also, Read this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-filters-in-opencart--cms-22594) for more information. [Click Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-filters-in-opencart--cms-22594)